# Linux mint desktop menus styles and scrollbars are gone

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, gtk

I have mixed debian repos with ubuntu repos (and possibly another couple of things one is not supposed to do). Normally I can handle the problems, however this time I have screwed up my system a bit. Now my windows look like this

[image]

As you can see, the menus are pretty much on top of each other... if feels a lot like if the menus styling were done via html and css and the styles are no longer applied.

I am considering to simply reinstall my system (I have a /home partition) and give XFCE a shot, but before that, I think it is worth trying to fix this (most likely it is just reinstalling the correct package).

For the record I am using linux mint and cinnamon.

Comment: I am pretty sure though that this can be addressed and solved by simply installing the correct version of a certain package.